# SessionScoped getting different instances

Tags: jboss, cdi, weld

I'm getting different instances of a @SessionScoped bean for two calls to the same user session. What can lead to this?

A bean annotated @SessionScoped is injected into a servlet, and a RESTEasy JAX-RS web service endpoint. A user logs in using HTTPS with a certificate. First call goes to the RESTEasy endpoint. The next call from the browser goes to the servlet. I'd expect the same bean instance in both calls, but they are different. ... Any ideas?

Using JBoss 7.0.1

bean:

```
@Stateful
@SessionScoped
public class MyBean implements Serializable { ... }
```

REST endpoint:

```
@Path("/one")
public class MyService extends JAXRSPlugin { 
   @Inject MyBean myBean;
   ... 
}
```

Servlet:

```
@WebServlet(urlPatterns = "/two", asyncSupported = true)
public class MyServlet extends HttpServlet { 
   @Inject MyBean myBean;
   ... 
}
```

Comment: how do you determine that they are different?

Comment: I know they are different via my debugger. The instance ID is different. Used same method to verify that the HttpSession is the same instance, but I have to get it via a @Context injection of the HttpServletRequest in the REST service method.

Answer (score 1):

Turns out the REST service methods are not really supposed to have an HttpSession to share state. REST services are supposed to be stateless. They are given @SessionScoped beans as if they were @RequestScoped by design.

It's not what I want for this case, but maybe I should just not use REST for these calls. Mainly I just wanted the handy mapping of URL paths to methods in my REST service class. Servlets don't have path-to-method-mapping like that, as far as I know.

Basically I see 3 options: (1) make of find a dispatching mechanism to use in one Servlet, (2) use multiple Servlets, or (3) mis-use the REST by abusing the @Context HttpServletRequest to get to the HttpSession. I don't like abusing APIs, so option 3 is out. CDI might make option 2 cool, but option 1 is probably more common (and so might be easier to maintain by others).